# Report Today minus 1 day

Tags: db2, websphere

need help with this query DB2 IBM

```
SELECT 
  ABALPH AS Kunde,
  SDLITM AS Artikel,
  SDDSC1 AS Beschreibung,
  SDSOQS AS Menge, date(digits(decimal(SDIVD+1900000,7,0))) AS Invoice,
  decimal(SDUPRC/10000,15,2) AS Einzelpreis,
  decimal(SDAEXP/100,15,2) AS Gesamtpreis,
  SDDOCO AS Dokument,
  AIAC01 AS Region
```

Now my question is , how can I get the today date minus 1 day ?

Thank you so much

have test it with ADD_DAYS doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the point in your query where a date is referenced but your query seems incomlete anyways because join contions are missing.

In general you get todays date with current date and you get yesterday with current date - 1 day

Check out this query:

```
SELECT current date, current date - 1 day 
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [DB2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-add-days), ADD_DAYS is valid with negative numbers for previous days. See example 4 on that page.  So usage like this should have worked:

```
  ADD_DAYS(DATE(...), -1)
```

or

```
  ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE, -1)
```

You should post your specific attempted usage of it and the error that is reported when you try it.